# Newbie Question - How do I add content to this page?

Tags: panels, 7, nodes

I'm very new to drupal, and I've been put on this project.

So I wanted to create a custom page to display the privacy conditions, which is just a word file I have to copy (so just plain text).

I created the custom page, used the template they gave me and now I want to add the plain text, however I have no Idea where I can do that. Normally I should be able to do it on this page they told, but I can't figure out why I can't change the Main Content.

[image: Page Options]

Sorry for this very silly question, but I can't find anything about this on the internet.

Comment: You shouldn't use a sledgehammer like panels to create a basic page with privacy conditions.  Get hold of somebody that knows something about Drupal and get them to help you re-enable the "Basic page" content type. Then use that for your static text.

Answer (score 0):

Am not clear about your requirement, right now you are trying to display it using a panels. If your requirement is just to show a custom page with custom text.. then just add a basic page as a content and place the text in body field. Then call the page using the given path.

Comment: ye that's what I wanted to do, but I can't find the content type "basic page" in content types (it's a custom theme some guy made)

Comment: just check content -> add content -> basic page from admin menu on top. otherwise type this path "admin/content" and then proceed with add content.

Comment: Nope, it's on in the list. http://puu.sh/iSAp8/17e803bd78.png I think the guy from the theme disabled it.

Comment: May be the basic page content type is deleted. create a new content type and then create node using this new type with your content. Then dispaly it using panels.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using "Add content" link to create a new "node". If you don't have such link (yet), then it must be that you have no permission (yet) to add content ...